# ASP.NET Entity Framework Warning "Restore Using"

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have tried to research what this warning code is telling me, but I still don't understand.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression StateWarning    NU1701  Package 'EntityFramework 6.1.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: Since your application is targeting .NET Core 3.1, you can't use EF 6.1.0 as it is compatible with only .NET Framework 4.6+. You must add the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.0` from Nuget for .NET Core apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityFramework 6.1 does not support .NET Core.  EntityFramework 6.3 and later do.

So bump up your EF version to version 6.4, and this warning should go away.  You can also consider migrating to EF Core 3.x, but it's not a drop-in replacement for EntityFramework 6.